# store folders in package contents (bundle resources) in xcode 4.0 

Tags: xcode, ios, resources, xcode4, bundle

I need to store a folder in the package contents, not all files in the project all in one root folder.

How can I do this in XCode 4.0?

Right now I am going to the Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources to attempt these changes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create your folder in the filesystem, then drag it to the resource folder in XCode. In the following dialog select create folder reference for any added folder. The folder should be blue. This folder is copied to your bundle with its contents.

Comment: Are files inside the folder copied as well. Inside the bundler (project.app) I see the folders that I copied but the files are missing.

Comment: @surajz that is strange, the contents should be copied as well. The contents which are copied are not updated automatically as far as I know. It does help to open and close the folder so XCode updates the list of files/folders to be copied.