# Acces Ressource-Files with Full-"Group"-Path

Tags: xcode, path

I've created Groups in my XCode-Project with the hope, that I can use the full Path to Access the Files. The Problem is, that I can access an image that is located in PROJECT/Book/Book1/page1.png only with the name "page1". But if I now add a Book2-Group with also an page1.png in it, I will get problem I think. So I want to access them with the Full-Path.

How is that Possible?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720478/store-folders-in-package-contents-bundle-resources-in-xcode-4-0/5723182#5723182), the answer should solve your problem.

With smart groups in your resource folder everything is copied to root in the bundle, which will result in name conflicts for files which are named the same.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the Link, it works great to use the absolute paths now in the simulator. But it seems like they can't be opened on the device, but the files are copied to it. I used @    NSURL *path_xml = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"book" withExtension:@"xml" subdirectory:@"Books/Book1"]; to open a XML File, and it only works on the simulator. Any solutions for this behavior?